# python error UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types

Tags: python, string, numpy, date, concatenation

i'm new to python and i'm having an issue executiong this piece of code:

```py
import numpy as np

DatetimeIndex(['1990-03-31', '1990-06-30', '1990-09-30', '1990-12-31',
               '1991-03-31', '1991-06-30', '1991-09-30', '1991-12-31',
               '1992-03-31', '1992-06-30',
               ...
               '2015-09-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-03-31', '2016-06-30',
               '2016-09-30', '2016-12-31', '2017-03-31', '2017-06-30',
               '2017-09-30', '2017-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=112, freq='Q-DEC')
proj_index = np.char.array(proj_index.year)+'Q'+np.char.array(proj_index.quarter)`
```

desired result: proj_index array would be [....'2017Q1', '2017Q2', '2017Q3'...]

here is the error i'm getting:  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.bytes_") to str.

to fix it i tried these steps:

```
`f=np.char.array(proj_index.year)
k=f.decode()
b=np.char.array(proj_index.quarter)
y=b.decode()
m=k+'Q'+y`
```

then i got another error again : UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U4'), dtype('<U1')) -> None

it would be really kind if someone could help me please
thank you in advance

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: don't try to use `np.char.array`..  Dataframe and Series (columns) have a perfectly good `values` or `to_numpy()` methods.  Your errors have to do with mixing char and bytestring arrays, and with "adding" strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is `proj_index` :

```
import pandas as pd

proj_index = pd.date_range("1990-03-31", "2017-12-31", freq="Q-DEC") # or an equivalent
```

You can use [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) or [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html?highlight=periodindex) with a *Quarter* `frequency` :

```
out = proj_index.to_period("Q") # or pd.PeriodIndex(proj_index, freq="Q")
```

Output :

```
PeriodIndex(['1990Q1', '1990Q2', '1990Q3', '1990Q4', '1991Q1', '1991Q2',
             '1991Q3', '1991Q4', '1992Q1', '1992Q2',
             ...
             '2015Q3', '2015Q4', '2016Q1', '2016Q2', '2016Q3', '2016Q4',
             '2017Q1', '2017Q2', '2017Q3', '2017Q4'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]', length=112)
```

Comment: **NB**: If you need a *NumPy* array, use `out.astype(str).values` or a list, `out.astype(str).tolist()`.